# Passing parameters for posting an item to Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

I have a code for post to Facebook but in parameters I have to add my own but its not working for me.
I have these 3 things to post my Facebook i.e. title, description, date time.

```
let notSureItem = NotSureItem()
            notSureItem.title = self.textField.text!
            notSureItem.textDescription = self.textAreaDescription.text!
            notSureItem.dateTime = self.dateTime
```

I have this code for posting to Facebook.

```
if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil){
                if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().hasGranted("publish_actions") {
                    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/feed", parameters: ["message": "hello"], HTTPMethod: "POST").startWithCompletionHandler({
                        (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                        if !(error != nil) {
                            NSLog("Post id:%@", result["id"])
                        }

                    })
                }
            }
```

In parameters I had passed a message which is successfully post on Facebook but if I had to pass parameters which I had stated above how to do that.
If anyone can help thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem. Simply passed as string and its work.

```
if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil){
                if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().hasGranted("publish_actions") {
                    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/feed", parameters: ["message": "\(self.textField.text!)\n \(self.textAreaDescription.text!)\n \(self.dateTime)"], HTTPMethod: "POST").startWithCompletionHandler({
                        (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                        if !(error != nil) {
                            NSLog("Post id:%@", result["id"])
                        }

                    })
                }
            }
```